# How to do not get lost on github project forks

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I find it quite difficult get a overview on the github structure of a project and its dozen of forks.

Is there some kind of visualization that shows a common tree with all repos and their differences (shown as branches)?

If visiting a project that was not maintained for some years there may be forks that fix things or implement features that were not pulled back.
However, most of the forks may do not have any changes or were pulled back. Those could be filtered from the view.

But how to find out?

Is there some github feature I missed or some external site/tool?

Comment: Did you look at [network graph](https://help.github.com/en/articles/viewing-a-repositorys-network) ?

Comment: @GauravSingh cool -  yes something like this i had in mind. you might post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Network graph](https://help.github.com/en/articles/viewing-a-repositorys-network)

In Github's words

> The network graph displays the branch history of the entire repository network, including branches of the root repository and branches of forks that contain commits unique to the network.